# Theorem Solution by Resolution Refutation

Tags: artificial-intelligence, predicate, theorem-proving

I have the following problem which I need to solve by resolution method in Artificial Intelligence

[image]

I don't understand why the negation of dog(x) is added in the first clause and ///y in the fourth clause why negation of animal(Y) is added ...

I mean what is the need of negation there?

Comment: Check this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776038/predicate-logic-in-clause-form

Comment: which book is this from?

Comment: @JerzyDziewierz Artificial Intelligence by Luger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that logical implication `P → Q` is equivalent to `¬P ∨ Q`. You can verify this by looking at the truth table:

```
   P Q  P → Q
   0 0    1
   1 0    0
   0 1    1
   1 1    1
```

Now clearly `dog(X) → animal(X)` is equivalent to `¬dog(X) ∨ animal(X)` which is a disjunction of literals therefore is *a clause*.

The same reasoning applies to `animal(Y) → die(Y)`.

As soon as you have got a set of formulas in clausal form that is equivalent to your input knowledge base, you can apply binary resolution to check if your knowledge base is consistent, or to prove a goal.

To prove a goal you add a negation of it to your consistent knowledge base and see if the knowledge base with the added negation of the goal becomes inconsistent.